# Proving $I\subseteq\sqrt I$ in a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. How can this directly be proved?

P.S: I tried to take an element from the left side and then get to the other side but it didn't work out. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: An element $a$ of $\sqrt{I}$ satisfies $a^n \in I$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Can you see why $a^n \in I$ for all $a \in I$?

Comment: If $a\in I$ then $a^1\in I$ then $a^1\in\sqrt I$.

Comment: @cofnmarol No. would you mind help me and explain it?

Comment: @nima It looks like what you’re missing is a definition for $\sqrt I$.  If you had that then it is hard to see where to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{I} = \{a \in R : a^{n} \in I$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Take $a \in I \subset R$  then $a^{1} = a \in I$, then $a \in \sqrt{I}$